# How to call web api in html page using jquery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am learning web api where I have created a html page and I want to get `<ul>` list in my html page.

To call api i have used Jquery ajax call to do so but seems not working. I debugged Jquery but getting no error.

Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var listitem = $('#ulEmployees');

            $('#btn').click(function () {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    Type: 'GET',
                    url: 'api/employees',
                    dataType: JSON,
                    success: function (data) {
                        listitem.empty();
                        debugger;
                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            var fullname = val.FirstName + ' ' + val.LastName;
                            listitem.append('<li>' + fullname + '</li>');

                        });
                    }

                });
            });

            $('#btnClear').click(function () {
                listitem.empty();
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn" value="Get All Employees" type="button" />
    <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" />
    <ul id="ulEmployees"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Web api `GET` method

```
 public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string gender="All")
        {
            using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                switch(gender.ToLower())
                {
                    case "all":
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.ToList());
                    case "male":
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "male").ToList());
                    case "female":
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "female").ToList());
                    default:
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Not found");

                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: What is your API url ? Is it in the same domain as your UI Screen?

Comment: _"but seems not working"_ what happens instead? What is the expected result in `data`?

Comment: @Baskar, Yes it is under the same project where I have created my api. That is the reason, I have used relative path for that.

Comment: @Jasen, When I click on button, only button event fires up and then it never goes to success part.

Comment: @Aarav remove datatype JSON and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype should not be passed. Your function should be like below with out datatype as JSON. Internally in jquery the call will fail while it is trying to convert datatype with .toLower function.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    Type: 'GET',
                    url: 'api/employees',                        
                    success: function (data) {
                        listitem.empty();
                        debugger;
                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            var fullname = val.FirstName + ' ' + val.LastName;
                            listitem.append('<li>' + fullname + '</li>');

                        });
                    }

                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, Baskar! It helped me to solve the problem.